# Friction in stopping a book

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, kinematics, momentum

[image]

Let us imagine we have a book on a table. We want to push the table in such a way such that the book doesn't move with the table,instead it falls down vertically(assuming there is friction on the surface between the book and the table).This is a real life scenario which is possible. But i don't get the logic behind this happening since i deduced that the book will also move horizontally.

Let us suppose we push the table with force $F$. Now,we consider the free body diagrams of the book and the table seperately. Here,the table is moving forward. So,to prevent relative motion,the table will apply frictional force $f$ on the book. And by Newton's third law,the book will also apply force $f$ on the table. But here in the $+x$ direction,the frictional force $f$ is working on the block. So,won't the book always accelerate,hence move in the $+x$ direction? One answer i thought of that if $f$ is less than limiting friction,then the book wouldn't move. If we apply a force on any object less than the limiting friction, then a frictional force equal to the applied force acts in the *opposite direction* to nullify the applied force. *But here the friction itself is being applied on the book and there is no force to act in the opposite direction to nullify this frictional force $f$*. But such scenarios of the book falling vertically down are possible in real life. So,i want to know where i am making the mistake.

Answer (score 0):

In the limit at which the table is pulled infinitely fast, the friction force acting on the book acts over an infinitesimally small time, and hence creates a negligible impulse, so that the book acquires a negligible horizontal momentum.

Comment: I am sorry,i don't get you. My main concern was only frictional force acts on the book. *Now saying that if the frictional force is less than the limiting friction then the book won't move*,Isn't it the same as saying that another frictional force will act in the bakcward direction to nullify the forward frictional force? I can't understand how two friction acting on the same object makes sense.

Comment: @madness It's just the one friction force, acting over a negligible timeframe